# Monorepo with paths from Typescript is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have monorepo (yarn workpaces) with following file structure:

```
├── client                (workspace @client)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json     (extended tsconfig)
├── server                (workspace @server)
│   ├── getData.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json     (extended tsconfig)
├── shared
│   └── sanitizeData.ts
├── package.json          (monorepo root)
└── tsconfig.json         (base tsconfig)
```

And I want to use function from `shared/sanitizeData.ts` in `server/getData.ts`

I tried to use `paths` from Typescript, it looks pretty straightforward according to docs, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@shared/sanitizeData'.
```

`server/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "../",
    "outDir": "build",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

`server/getData.js`:

```js
import { sanitizeData } from "@shared/sanitizeData";
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 8):

Paths are relative to `baseUrl`, so in your case you'd have to replace `["shared/*"]` with `["../shared/*"]`

Comment: This answer is correct, but one should also keep in mind that paths are **overwritten** - they are not merged! Adding the possibility to merge arrays in `tsconfig.json` is being discused in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20110).

Answer (score 4):

Define the baseUrl only in the root tsconfig file, to prevent rebasing complexities.
Then, references all paths from baseurl.

Remember:
The paths property does not merge entries from multiple tsconfig files... as the "extends" argument implies.
Paths of a base tsconfig get overwritten by the paths in the derived tsconfig.

So, you'll have to copy/move the paths from the base tsconfig to any derived tsconfig files.

And, be sure to decorate any path alias with a '@' so that it's distinguishable from other relative paths.
I say this, because an import from "commonlib/src" is not obvious to be a path alias, and could simply be a relative path from the local src.
But, "@commonlib/src" is easily recognized as a path alias, since '@' is not a legal leading folder/file character.