# How to configure module aliases in a monorepo bootstrapped with Turborepo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, turborepo

I am attempting to migrate several repositories to the monorepo architecture and I am currently working on a POC bootstrapped with [Turborepo](https://turbo.build/).

The issue I am seeing is that ts module aliasing isn't configured properly. I currently have a single ui package and I am trying to export a button component from the `index.tsx` like so (notice, VS code not complaining, it thinks it can resolve the module):

[image: VS Code2]

However, when I attempt to build my application I see that the module is not in fact resolved:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/Button'

I am at a loss here, does anyone know how to properly configure module aliases with turbo repo? Below is the tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/react-library.json",
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["./components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the `tsconfig.json` inside both **packages/ui** and **root**.

1. Inside the **packages/ui** you have to set like the paths like this;

```js
// root/packages/ui -> tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/react-library.json",
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"] // Don't use "./components/*", instead like this: "components/*" 
    }
  }
}
```

2. `tsconfig.json` in root also.

```js
// root -> tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "your_default_extends",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{your_plugins}],
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./packages/ui/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["your_include"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If you have another project wanna using import @ alias as well, just add the route to the folder inside root `tsconfig.json` too.

```js
// root -> tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "your_default_extends",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{your_plugins}],
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./packages/ui/*", "./apps/some_project/src/*"] // here
    }
  },
  "include": ["your_include"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58554760/9640177) thread. You will have to do a little bit of trial and error to get this right. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73989946/9640177) answer will get us in the right direction.